# Is this sentence correct : "I would have never believed that it would become like that"

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

I said that in the past : "I don't believe (and I am sure) that it will become like that" (when I speak I am in the past).

Now we are in the present and I say to talk about this past : "I would have never believed that it would become like that" (I am surprised).

Is my sentence correct?

Comment: I would use the simple past. I didn't believe that it would turn out like that.

Comment: The construction *become like* didn't sound right to me. But I see there's been a substantial discussion of it at: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109294/is-become-like-valid-english-words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You are correctly expressing in a very emphatic way that in the past you would not have believed "that it would become like that".